# QT Decorationrole gets overwritten by decorationrole child

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qtreewidget, qitemdelegate

I have made a treewidget within a navigation panel. The top item consist of the following three "subitems"

**ActorColor | DeviceName | DeviceStatus (LED)**

One layer lower, the child of this top item consists of the following subitems

**Actorcolor | Title**

(See image below)

This is how it looks like. The top item is called Test_01 and the layer item is called "Color: #ea6852"

[image]

This all goes well with updating etcetera. However, as soon as I click the layer item, the LED in the top layer gets replaced by an orange square.
Both are defined as DecorationRoles in a custom **`QTreeItemDelegate`**

[image: Function]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code, ideally something that reproduces the problem in the simplest way possible. It would help if you used real names of classes, properly capitalized. `QTreeWidget` vs. "treewidget" for example to be perfectly clear what you mean. There's no `QTreeItemDelegate` so that must be your custom one but we don't know anything about it. Cheers. Also not clear what you mean by "both are defined as DecorationRoles" -- there's only one of those per item, so I'm not sure how the green circle is even being shown there to begin with.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi Maxim/Eyllanesc,

Thanks for your response; Above in the description I have provided a part of the code wherein I implement this feature.

Comment: "Reproducible" means someone else can run it. Pretty hard to do with an image of code. And incomplete code at that. Still not even clear if you're using a QTreeWidget or QTreeView. (To reply to comments so that your recipient(s) are notified, use the [@ username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) system).